# Forward variadic arguments based on conditions

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to achieve following behavior:

```
enum class Fruit {
 Apple,
 Orange,
 Pear,
};

template<typename... Args>
void processFruit(Fruit fruit_type, Args&&... args) {
 switch (fruit_type) {
   case Apple:
     processApple(std::forward<Args>args...);
     break;
   case Orage:
     processOrange(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
     break;
   default:
     break;
 }
 postProcessing();
 return;
}
```

`processApple` and `processOrange` take different number of arguments.
This of course cannot compile. Compiler cannot instantiate functions based on the `switch` statement. I found some suggestions on `static_if`. Just wondering if there's a simpler way for my situation. Thanks.

p.s. my platform restricts me on C++14 solutions.

Comment: I would get rid of the `fruit_type` parameter, and just overload `processFruit()` for each type of supported fruit. Then have the variadic version of `processFruit()` loop through its `args` calling the overloaded `processFriut()` for each parameter

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The intension is to interface with another module which would provide more APIs in the future. Also for different fruit types, we might also have same `args` structure. Just wondering if I can use meta programming to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question muddies the waters a bit, because you're mixing runtime and compile-time logic, because in your case the number and types of function arguments depends on the runtime value of something.

You're now stuck with two different options: it is possible to make this work (even in just C++14), but any call site that doesn't pass the correct arguments will not be detected until runtime. The way to do so is with the help of `std::enable_if_t`, `decltype()` and `std::declval`. I've done this for your example, and the following compiles for me in C++14 mode:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <stdexcept>

enum class Fruit {
Apple,
Orange,
Pear,
};

void processApple(int a, int b);
void processOrange(int c);
void processPear(double d);
void postProcessing();

struct Processor
{
    template<typename... Ts, typename = decltype(processApple(std::forward<Ts>(std::declval<Ts>())...))>
    static void process(std::integral_constant<Fruit, Fruit::Apple>, Ts&&... ts)
    {
        processApple(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }

    template<typename... Ts, typename = decltype(processOrange(std::forward<Ts>(std::declval<Ts>())...))>
    static void process(std::integral_constant<Fruit, Fruit::Orange>, Ts&&... ts)
    {
        processOrange(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }

    template<typename... Ts, typename = decltype(processPear(std::forward<Ts>(std::declval<Ts>())...))>
    static void process(std::integral_constant<Fruit, Fruit::Pear>, Ts&&... ts)
    {
        processPear(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }

    [[noreturn]] static void process(...)
    {
        // While this is inserted, it should never be called in practice,
        // unless there's a programming error.
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid argument specified to processFruit().");
    }
};

template<typename... Args>
void processFruit(Fruit fruit_type, Args&&... args) {
    switch (fruit_type) {
    case Fruit::Apple:
        Processor::process(std::integral_constant<Fruit, Fruit::Apple>(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        break;
    case Fruit::Orange:
        Processor::process(std::integral_constant<Fruit, Fruit::Orange>(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        break;
    case Fruit::Pear:
        Processor::process(std::integral_constant<Fruit, Fruit::Pear>(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    postProcessing();
    return;
}

void processApple(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << "Apple: " << a << " // " << b << std::endl;
}

void processOrange(int c)
{
    std::cout << "Orange: " << c << std::endl;
}

void processPear(double d)
{
    std::cout << "Pear: " << d << std::endl;
}

void postProcessing()
{
    std::cout << "Post processing" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    processFruit(Fruit::Apple, 4, 8);
    processFruit(Fruit::Orange, 15);
    processFruit(Fruit::Pear, 1.234);
    // The following will only throw an exception, but not fail to compile
    //processFruit(Fruit::Pear, 1.234, 77);
    return 0;
}
```

(The `struct Processor` is just to clean up the namespace, they could be global functions.) Problem here is that the compiler can't detect a wrong call, see the commented out call to `processFruit(Fruit::Pear, 1.234, 77);` that would generate an exception, but the compiler couldn't detect it at compile time.

In my eyes this is not very sensible though. Since the arguments depend on the `Fruit` type anyway, I don't really see how you could even perform a call to one of these functions when the `Fruit` argument is only known at runtime, because each call site will only work for a single type.

And if you do know that at compile time anyway, this could be done in a much simpler way via overloads, that also allows for much better compile-time diagnostics:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class Fruit {
Apple,
Orange,
Pear,
};

void processApple(int a, int b);
void processOrange(int c);
void processPear(double d);
void postProcessing();

template<typename... Args>
void processFruit2Helper(std::integral_constant<Fruit, Fruit::Apple>, Args&&... args)
{
    processApple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // or put the code of processApple directly in here
}

template<typename... Args>
void processFruit2Helper(std::integral_constant<Fruit, Fruit::Orange>, Args&&... args)
{
    processOrange(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // or put the code of processOrange directly in here
}

template<typename... Args>
void processFruit2Helper(std::integral_constant<Fruit, Fruit::Pear>, Args&&... args)
{
    processPear(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // or put the code of processPear directly in here
}

template<Fruit f, typename... Args>
void processFruit2(Args&&... args)
{
    processFruit2Helper(std::integral_constant<Fruit, f>(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    postProcessing();
}

void processApple(int a, int b)
{
    std::cout << "Apple: " << a << " // " << b << std::endl;
}

void processOrange(int c)
{
    std::cout << "Orange: " << c << std::endl;
}

void processPear(double d)
{
    std::cout << "Pear: " << d << std::endl;
}

void postProcessing()
{
    std::cout << "Post processing" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    processFruit2<Fruit::Apple>(4, 8);
    processFruit2<Fruit::Orange>(15);
    processFruit2<Fruit::Pear>(1.234);

    // The following will fail to compile here (which is good)
    //processFruit2<Fruit::Pear>(1.234, 77);
    return 0;
}
```

That all said, I suspect there's some higher-level design problem in your code, but we won't be able to understand that with the limited example you've provided.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The second one is what I am looking for. I wasn't clear in my question. But `Fruit` type for me is known at compile time.